# Linux 64 bit BAR programming

Tags: linux, pci-e

A PCI bridge supports 32/64 pref/no pref:

```
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff] 
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x1000000000-0x10ffffffff] (bus address [0x00000000-0xffffffff])
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x1100000000-0x11ffffffff pref] (bus address [0x00000000-0xffffffff])
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x2000000000-0x2fffffffff] (bus address [0x00000000-0xfffffffff])
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x3000000000-0x3fffffffff pref] (bus  address [0x00000000-0xfffffffff])
```

Scans an endpoint with 2 BARs:

```
pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 2: assigned [mem 0x2100000000-0x211fffffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x1000000000-0x100007ffff]
```

The bridge shows the windows:

```
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x1000000000-0x10000fffff]
pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x2100000000-0x211fffffff 64bit pref]
```

The endpoint summarizes the BARs:

```
endpoint: BAR 0 addr = 0x1000000000, size = 524287
endpoint: BAR 1 addr = 0x2100000000, size = 536870911
```

What would the upper 32 bits of BAR1 be programmed to? I expected 0x21, but find 0x1.

This is because of pcibios_bus_to_resource/pcibios_resource_to_bus.
It identifies 3 window offsets:

```
window->res->start = 1000000000 window->offset = 1000000000 window->res->end = 10FFFFFFFF
window->res->start = 1100000000 window->offset = 1100000000 window->res->end = 11FFFFFFFF
window->res->start = 2000000000 window->offset = 2000000000 window->res->end = 2FFFFFFFFF
```

It adds the offset when displaying the addresses above, but subtracts them when programming the BAR
register in the endpoint. So 0x2100000000 becomes 0x100000000.

That might make sense with 64 bit addresses and 32 bit BARs, but why would that be correct with 64 bit BARs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this (taken from the question):

```
    pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x1000000000-0x10ffffffff] (bus address [0x00000000-0xffffffff])
    pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x1100000000-0x11ffffffff pref] (bus address [0x00000000-0xffffffff])
    pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x2000000000-0x2fffffffff] (bus address [0x00000000-0xfffffffff])
    pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x3000000000-0x3fffffffff pref] (bus  address [0x00000000-0xfffffffff])
```

memory address 0x20'0000'0000 corresponds to bus address 0.

So the BAR in the device needs to be programmed to 0x1'0000'0000 if it is to be accessed using memory address 0x21'0000'0000.

Similarly, memory address 0x10'0000'0000 corresponds to bus address 0. So the BAR in the device is programmed to 0 to be accessed using memory address 0x10'0000'0000.